# Is it possible to redraw (change fill color or apply transformation) a single CGPath or everything must be redrawn?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I've got a set of CGPath drawn inside an UIVIew with an UIImage being used as a sort of canvas (imagine a map with some highlights).

Each of these paths is drawn with a fill and border color.

The business logic of this view says that when the object (represented by a path) goes to another sate (ex: Busy, InMaintenance), it must change its border or fill color.

At this point I'm updating an element of the list of objects and call SetNeedsDisplay.

The Draw is called and everything is redrawned.

Is there a better way to do this? Can I just change redraw a single path?

Thanks,

Luis Pinho

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do that. You need to redraw the entire region that has been exposed.

If there was a single item that you expect will change a lot, but the rest will remain static, you could use two different views or layers. One would contain the static context and the other would contain the updated context.   The one with the updated context would have a transparent background, and you would position this on top of the other.

That way, you would only redraw that view/layer.

Comment: Hi Miguel, 1st I would like to thank you and all the team for Xamarin :) All the docs that I've read say something similar, do you think that the technique, draw to bitmap and show it, is more effective then drawing to screen (in mobile)?